# Product Price + First Custom Option Price in products list?

Tags: magento2.3, price, custom-options, product-list

We sell product which, for some of them, must include one option (which has a fixed price of, say, 50$)

On the product list views + on the product page we would like to show the price as : "Starting at " (Product Price + First Option Price) $

For ex :
- product price : 100$
- First custom option : 50$

==> "Starting at 150$" in list of products and product page (anywhere in front end site in fact)

Can this be done natively or via an extension ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: which Magento version please

Comment: Magento 2.3 to the latest patch